# location of software updates in 10.6

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

When software update runs and downloads in the background for you before you choose to install... where are those files stored?

I had thought it was /Library/Packages however I can't find that directory in my Snow Leopard machine. (even with terminal)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe they're actually stored in /Library/Updates and then are deleted as soon as they're installed.

Comment: This seems to be the right answer. Thank you very much - it will help make an installation disk image smaller!

Answer (score 1):

Just copied the Updates from Snow Leopard 10.6.8 from /Library/Updates/_RANDOM_FOLDERS_

And each App will have a separate Random Folder, all you have to do is, to wait for the Updates to show, and they won't show until they're totally finished, so you can rest assured they're complete, and all you have to do is to copy them right away, because they'll be automatically removed after they're installed.

And all the Files were in .pkg format by the way.

Answer (score 0):

It might be under `/var/folders`, which is apparently Snow Leopard's preferred location for caches and temp files now. Unfortunately, some of the folder names under `/var/folders` seem to be somewhat randomly generated, so I can't give you a static path. Try this:

```
sudo find /var/folders -name '*SoftwareUpdate*'
```

I don't have any downloaded-but-not-installed updates right now, so my software-update-related directories under there are mostly empty at the moment, so I can't confirm for sure if this is the right place.